# Uncaught google.earth not loaded

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-earth-plugin

I'm doing this to add Google Earth to Google Maps v3:

```
  google.load("earth", "1");

  // map options
  var options = mapster.MAP_OPTIONS,
  element = document.getElementById('map-canvas'),

  // map
  map = mapster.create(element, options);

  var ge = new GoogleEarth(map);
```

The script on my html file looks like this:

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
  <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script src="googleearth.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
```

I keep getting `Uncaught google.earth not loaded` and not sure what I did wrong.

I'm using this reference: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/googleearth/docs/reference.html

Here's my full code in case it helps: http://plnkr.co/edit/NlPF3F259IIMgj2pfN09?p=preview

I really want to add Google Earth to Google Maps like the one in here: http://maps.google.com
Is it possible with v3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - it is possible to integrate the Earth Api with the Maps v3 API - here is a [working example](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/googleearth/examples/earth.html).

The problem with your code is the line `var ge = new GoogleEarth(map);` - you are making this call before the Earth api has finished loading via the asynchronous call to `google.load("earth", "1");`

This means that `google.earth` is null when you try and use it and so the `Uncaught google.earth not loaded` error is thrown.

To fix it you should only call `new GoogleEarth(map)` once the API has finished loading. The easiest way to do this is probably to use a callback.

For example - you could amend your `script.js` as follows.

```
(function(window, google, mapster) {

  google.load("earth", "1");

  // map options
  var options = mapster.MAP_OPTIONS,
      element = document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      map = mapster.create(element, options);

  // callback method to fire once the api had loaded
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {  new GoogleEarth(map) });

  var marker2 = map.addMarker({
    lat: 37.781350,
    lng: -122.485883,
    draggable: true,
    events: [{
      name: 'click',
      callback: function(e, marker) {
        console.log(e, marker);
      }
    }, {
      name: 'dragend',
      callback: function() {
        alert('dragged');
      }
    }]
  }); 

  // no point calling this here as google.earth will be null
  //var ge = new GoogleEarth(map); 

}(window, google, window.Mapster));
```

Comment: Got an error when using the callback (`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`). But I viewed the source of the working example which works perfectly. Maybe there's something with using `google.load` inside self invoking anonymous function. Thanks so much for your help, and the working sample!

Comment: Odd - I tested the code and it worked. Anyhow glad to help. If you mark the answer as correct people will be more likely to help you in future too.

Comment: Ah - ok got it - when I pasted the code I had the first two statements back-to-front.